# History pane on iPad breaks new design

Tags: bug, design, ipad

The new design seems to work reasonably well on my iPad (2018, 9.7”, iOS 12.1.4), until I open the History (aka Reading List / Bookmarks) pane. This causes the page to shrink in width (as expected?) but the page shrinks such that the page is *under* the pane, not to the right of it.

I can’t consistently reproduce this, but I do have a screenshot of it:

[image]

Comment: And the history pane isn't an overlay like that on other sites?  (I don't have an iPad, so I've no idea how this is supposed to work.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio it’s sometimes an overlay, sometimes the page resizes for it. Either way, it’s not supposed to cause the right third to be empty.

Comment: True, something weird is going on over on the right.